# I can't debug, mscorlib.dll error

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, dll, visual-studio-2015

When i start my project (in Debug or Release, Visual Studio 2015), I get this error:

[image: Error on start project]

I tried to repair my .NET framework, but I got no success, I cant debug this error because it isn't code error.

Which can cause it?

How can I repair it?

How to prevent this?

Comment: can you post the code?

Comment: @downrep_nation this error happens anywhere, when this happens the solution stop and i need to rebuild

Comment: @downrep_nation the error appear in any window where i focus after the projet start

Comment: try a restart and see

Comment: @Mir no difference

Comment: Does it happen in any new project you create? Can you get to the [call stack](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a3694ts5.aspx) when it happens?

Comment: @GSerg This happen only to this project, no the call stack dont shows up, and my project stops randomly, sometimes i can use it for 5 minutes or i get this error after all libriries load. My published project works fine.

Answer (score 0):

A `NullReferenceException` occurs when you try to access an object/method/variable which has no value or technically has a value of `null`, for example:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main(string[] args)
   {
      int value = Int32.Parse(args[0]);
      List<String> names;
      if (value > 0)
         names = new List<String>();

      names.Add("Major Major Major");       
   }
}
```

> source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nullreferenceexception(v=vs.110).aspx

In the code above. The program will create a list of strings called `names` and then on an **IF**-statement it will instantiate the list of names, and since the only way the list will be instantiated is IF a **CONDITIONAL** statement succeeds and conditional statements are commonly known to not always be true.

So therefore the code will be like this, A list of strings called names is created and equals `null` (because the programmer did not equal it to anything like this; `List<string> names;` instead of this;
`List<string> names = new List<string>();`

The code above, I gave you can also cause a `NullPointerException` (If the if-statement and the code inside it, is removed).

---

So to fix that we would need to remove the If statement altogether and instantiate the list of names, so the code will now look like this.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Example
{
   public static void Main(string[] args)
   {
      int value = Int32.Parse(args[0]);
      List<String> names = new List<String>();

      names.Add("Major Major Major");       
   }
}
```

Another example:

```
string i;
if(i == "hello") {/*Do something*/} 
// Causes error because I is not set to any value or null
// (null is mostly the default variable given to any object/method/variable that is not specified to contain any value specified by the programmer)
```

Fix:

```
string i;
i = "hi";
if(i == "hello") {/*Do something*/} 
// Will not throw exception but returns false because I is set to hi and not hello
//Or you could just do this int i = 1; and remove the "i = 1" part
```

P.S: I hope you haven't figured this out before I answered your question, otherwise my effort to explain and answer your question would've been useless.

Comment: It is frowned upon when a common question is answered instead of being closed as [duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4660142/11683). However the OP's question is not in fact common, and this answer is both irrelevant (because the exception happens not in the user code) and wrong (because `int` can never contain `null`).

Comment: Oh wow you are right I hit a realization, even though this doesn't answer the main question(the title), However this does answer the questions that he asks as well. Which/What can cause it? How can I repair/fix it? How to prevent/fix this? but what I realized that the exception occured in mscorlib.dll and not in his code... So now his/her question seems more like a bug report to me.